# Using sleep_until on GCP Workflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workflows

Given a json input:

```
{"description":"12345","schedule_date":"2023-05-17T15:04:07+0000"}
```

This is the yaml for GCP workflow:

```
main:
  params: [task]
  steps:
    - waitScheduleDate:
        call: sys.sleep_until
        args:
            time: time.parse(${task.schedule_date})

    - createTask:
        call: http.post
        args:
          url: https://typedwebhook.tools/webhook/0e74a54b-8e57-40f3-8a78-10a25b0ebb89
          body: 
            date: ${task.schedule_date}
            description: ${task.description}
        result: task_output
    - returnOutput:
        return: ${task_output}
```

I am getting

```
ValueError: unknown format "time.parse(${task.schedule_date})"
in step "waitScheduleDate", routine "main", line: 5
{
  "message": "ValueError: unknown format \"time.parse(${task.schedule_date})\"",
  "tags": [
    "ValueError"
  ]
```

How to pass a date ISO-8601 string format as input for sys.sleep_until?

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mixed the things!!

- Sleep -> timestamp
- Sleep_until -> Date in String

```
    - waitScheduleDate:
        call: sys.sleep
        args:
            time: time.parse(${task.schedule_date})
```

or

```
    - waitScheduleDate:
        call: sys.sleep_until
        args:
            time: ${task.schedule_date}
```